# Embedding Power Bi into iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, business-intelligence, powerbi

Has anyone managed to embed power bi charts directly into an iOS application. For example to call a chart and embed it into a view controller? Is this even possible?

Comment: Are we talking "power bi embedded", or the Power BI service (aka powerbi.com)?

Comment: power bi embedded. Sorry for not being clear

Comment: It's not something I've done but I hope you can find an answer

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-For-Mobile

You can embed Power BI Embedded artifacts (Report, Dashboard, Tile, Q&A) in any webview based environment, including iOS Webview. 
You can either use a pre-set mobile layout and load it via the JS SDK in the config, or use custom layout: https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Custom-Layout

For a single chart\visual you can use: https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embed-Single-Visual

Answer (score 0):

Power BI reports can be embedded into a [web page](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-publish-to-web/), which you can display from [within your app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737237/loading-web-page-inside-ios-application).

From Power BI, click publish to web and then request an embed code.

Don't forget, if you don't like this approach you can always [request a new feature](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas).

**EDIT**

The [Power BI developer site](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-overview-of-power-bi-rest-api/) includes instructions for [integrating a dashboard](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-integrate-dashboard/) into your app.  This method uses the [Power BI Rest API](http://docs.powerbi.apiary.io/#introduction/authenticate-with-power-bi) to auth via Azure Active Directory and OAuth 2.0.

This approach has some limitations:

- The end users who access the embedded dashboards must have Power BI accounts and the dashboards should be shared with them.
- Currently Q&A is not supported in embedded dashboards.
- As a temporary limitation, when sharing a dashboard with security groups, user have to first access the dashboards in PowerBI.com before they can see it embedded.

Comment: Thank you for the response, however this method offers no security and the dashboards I'd like to embed are sensitive and cannot be exposed to the internet without security.

Comment: There is another method supported by Power BI, but I have no direct experience.  I'll edit the answer.